# How to convert UTF8 Base64 strings (email headers)?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, base64, decode

I have a lot of UTF8 Base64 strings that come from email headers, that look like this:

```
=?Utf-8?B?RW5jb2RlZCBTdHJpbmc===?=
```

The above string should convert to:

```
Encoded String
```

Does anyone here know how to decode these types of email headers using Javascript?

I am doing the following for now, but that's just super ugly, where I need to search and replace the beginning and end of those strings manually like this:

```js
var string = '=?Utf-8?B?VVRGOC1CYXNlNjQtU3RyaW5n==?=';
var decoded = string.replace("=?Utf-8?B?", "").replace("==?=", "");
decoded =  window.atob(decoded);
console.log(decoded);
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = decoded;
```

```html
<b>Encoded:</b><div>=?Utf-8?B?VVRGOC1CYXNlNjQtU3RyaW5n==?=</div>
<br>
<b>Decoded:</b><div id="res"></div>
```

For now, I am using it as a function, but there must be a better way than this:

```
function decodeBase64UTF8(from) {
 if (from.includes('=?Utf-8?B?')) {
 if (from.includes('?=')) {
 from = window.atob(from.replace("=?Utf-8?B?", "").replace("==?=", "").replace("?=", ""));
 return from;
}
} else {
return from;
}}
```

A demo of the function is here: https://jsfiddle.net/jarosciak/dmL7gnw6/

Comment: You can just use Dojo.js. Here's how to use it https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/encoding/base64.html

Comment: The moment there are non-ascii symbols in your headers, you will notice your code doesn't actually do what it says. You aren't doing anything regarding utf-8 at the moment.

Comment: dojo seems very heavy for something like this...